# Хранение данных в Application Android

Tags: java, android

Пишу игру под Аndroid.

У меня есть класс игры, в нем содержатся все данные. Сами данные я храню в файле.
То есть у меня есть вспомогательный класс, который умеет воссоздавать из текстового файла класс игры и наоборот записывать из данные в файл из класса игры.

Чего я хочу добиться. Я хочу, чтобы у меня был всего 1 класс игру и он создавался бы в методе `onCreate()` класса `Application`. Класс игры должен храниться именно в этом классе, ибо используется во многих `Activity`. После каждого изменения вызывать метод, который записывает измененный класс игры в файл выходит слишком затратно в плане времени.

Я подозреваю, что в классе `Application` есть какой-то метод, который вызывается при уничтожении этого объекта, то есть уничтожения самого приложения. И вот в этом методе мне и хотелось бы один раз загрузить на файл измененный класс игры.

Однако я все никак не могу понять что это за метод есть подозрения, что это либо

```
onTrimMemory(int level)
```

либо

```
onLowMemory()
```

Помогите решить вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: `есть какой-то метод` -- в общем случае нет такого метода.

Comment: а если игрок слишком далеко зайдет и у него сядет батарея?

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы хотите делать это очень плохая практика и со стороны структуры и со стороны поддержки кода и конечно же самой системы Android. Более того в Application классе нет такого метода (в дебаге есть), но есть воркэраунды, которые частично могут решить вашу проблему. Например: вы можете отслеживать жизненный цикл во всех Activity (Или создать свой базовый) или снимать StaceTrace из AcctivityManager там есть что-то вроде GET_TASK. Сделать логику например если нет тасок то можно считать, что приложение закрыто. Но опять это не стандартное поведение и я уверяю, что будут подводные камни в поведении самой системы.

Решение вашей задачи на самом деле простое это БД, действительно писать изменения данных в асинхронном порядке в БД это микрооперация, и потом уже дампить при необходимости в какой-то файл, если будет необходимость.

Comment: Бд мне не подйдет, у меня куча объектов разных классов, и пилить штук 30 бд под разные классы не совсем уместно, это если говорить о sql, а из nosql я нашел ток realm, и с ней у меня так же возникают проблемы. Данные однозначно мне надо хранить в фаиле и никак иначе. По крайней мере я не вижу варанта получше.